# Application Error with Ghost Blog

Tags: node.js, heroku, ghost-blog

I previously had [DOCPAD](http://docpad.org/) on my site. But want to use Ghost now. so I opened up my file and deleted docpad. Then I copied over the ghost files and ran `npm install` and I followed along with the tutorial at http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-on-heroku/ which said that I needed to add this to my project

**Procfile**

```
web: node index.js --production
```

I made this addition to my production settings

**config.js**

```
production: {
        url: 'http://hipsterux.com',
        mail: {},
        database: {
        client: 'postgres',
        connection: {
              host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
              user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
              password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
              database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
              port: '5432'
        },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: process.env.PORT
        }
    },
```

The tutorial did mention populating the variables and I did that.

Their was a section or possible errors. I did run `heroku ps` and got this

```
=== web (1X): `node index.js --production`
web.1: crashed 2014/02/11 10:28:48 (~ 1m ago)
```

Then I ran `heroku logs` and got this

```
2014-02-11T17:50:05.345134+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.395237+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.173.1.66 at 2014-02-11 17:50:47 +0000
2014-02-11T17:50:47.408701+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hipsterux.com request_id=dea3c298-70f1-45e4-bee8-d1133d074fe4 fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=3170
2014-02-11T17:50:47.396336+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-02-11T17:50:47.396336+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-02-11T17:50:47.397272+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.397272+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.398097+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.395237+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.173.1.66 at 2014-02-11 17:50:47 +0000
2014-02-11T17:50:47.398352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.398097+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.398352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.398619+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.398619+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-11T17:50:47.778189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-12747867e657ed75adbd7e34e5fac126.css host=hipsterux.com request_id=77c10885-e37b-47d8-97a5-8f694c2d6585 fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=12ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=103197
2014-02-11T17:50:49.685354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=hipsterux.com request_id=5ebdb01b-809a-4385-8167-7ee9d03170fe fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=0
2014-02-11T17:50:47.872706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/vendor/custom.modernizr-23d32674d619702e1e6f721f8a0110bc.js host=hipsterux.com request_id=eb556af3-4bac-4abf-bb3a-7166fb48087f fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=8875
2014-02-11T17:59:54+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-02-11T18:00:35.949284+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8eeb4da by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:00:35.993249+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v20 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:00:36+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-02-11T18:00:38.768597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-02-11T18:00:39.317225+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-02-11T18:00:36.383456+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-02-11T18:00:41.601036+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-02-11T18:00:41.892044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js --production`
2014-02-11T18:00:45.000457+00:00 app[web.1]: Url configured as: http://hipsterux.com
2014-02-11T18:00:45.000457+00:00 app[web.1]: Ctrl+C to shut down
2014-02-11T18:00:45.000457+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
2014-02-11T18:00:45.000457+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost is running in development...
2014-02-11T18:01:42.318086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-02-11T18:01:42.318303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-02-11T18:01:44.313445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-02-11T18:01:44.321830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-11T18:01:44.321034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-11T18:01:50.176265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js --production`
2014-02-11T18:01:55.064130+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost is running in development...
2014-02-11T18:01:55.064130+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
2014-02-11T18:01:55.064130+00:00 app[web.1]: Ctrl+C to shut down
2014-02-11T18:01:55.064130+00:00 app[web.1]: Url configured as: http://hipsterux.com
2014-02-11T18:02:50.698734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-02-11T18:02:50.699106+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-02-11T18:02:52.380345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-02-11T18:02:52.395869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-11T18:02:53.422199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterux.herokuapp.com request_id=5392ac5f-69f4-4a70-a506-7ca8c5fb7f40 fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-11T18:02:55.706704+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterux.com request_id=6b0869ee-1a73-4ac1-a4ae-75f0c440822f fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-11T18:02:53.722434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=hipsterux.herokuapp.com request_id=8d1ba006-1245-4761-b454-f3b97edd081d fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-11T18:19:34.348199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterux.com request_id=a2ba3171-8fd8-4e66-984a-fcac18b9e05d fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-11T18:26:03.064960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-11T18:26:06.605650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js --production`
2014-02-11T18:26:08.484215+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost is running in development...
2014-02-11T18:26:08.484215+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
2014-02-11T18:26:08.484215+00:00 app[web.1]: Url configured as: http://hipsterux.com
2014-02-11T18:26:08.484215+00:00 app[web.1]: Ctrl+C to shut down
2014-02-11T18:26:13.390665+00:00 heroku[api]: Add POSTGRES_USER config by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:26:13.419975+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v22 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:26:17.669462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js --production`
2014-02-11T18:26:20.344174+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost is running in development...
2014-02-11T18:26:20.344174+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
2014-02-11T18:26:20.344174+00:00 app[web.1]: Url configured as: http://hipsterux.com
2014-02-11T18:26:20.344174+00:00 app[web.1]: Ctrl+C to shut down
2014-02-11T18:26:28.386679+00:00 heroku[api]: Add POSTGRES_PASSWORD config by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:26:28.425811+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v23 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:26:32.714517+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js --production`
2014-02-11T18:26:34.914249+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost is running in development...
2014-02-11T18:26:34.914249+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
2014-02-11T18:26:34.914249+00:00 app[web.1]: Url configured as: http://hipsterux.com
2014-02-11T18:26:34.914249+00:00 app[web.1]: Ctrl+C to shut down
2014-02-11T18:26:40.227308+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js --production`
2014-02-11T18:26:42.296320+00:00 app[web.1]: Url configured as: http://hipsterux.com
2014-02-11T18:26:42.296320+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
2014-02-11T18:26:42.296320+00:00 app[web.1]: Ctrl+C to shut down
2014-02-11T18:26:42.296320+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost is running in development...
2014-02-11T18:27:01.521716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-02-11T18:27:03.778545+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-02-11T18:27:07.013815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-02-11T18:27:07.013626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-02-11T18:27:08.255667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-02-11T18:27:32.793553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-02-11T18:27:32.794307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-02-11T18:27:34.175685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-02-11T18:27:40.726958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-02-11T18:27:40.726758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-02-11T18:27:41.857674+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-02-11T18:27:41.870841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-11T18:27:41.869800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-11T18:27:45.868355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js --production`
2014-02-11T18:27:47.554877+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost is running in development...
2014-02-11T18:27:47.554877+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368
2014-02-11T18:27:47.554877+00:00 app[web.1]: Ctrl+C to shut down
2014-02-11T18:27:47.554877+00:00 app[web.1]: Url configured as: http://hipsterux.com
2014-02-11T18:26:02.871695+00:00 heroku[api]: Add POSTGRES_HOST config by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:26:02.919527+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v21 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:26:37.221794+00:00 heroku[api]: Add POSTGRES_DATABASE config by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:26:37.245498+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v24 created by jgallardo720@gmail.com
2014-02-11T18:28:46.018403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-02-11T18:28:46.018216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-02-11T18:28:47.402359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-11T18:28:47.362968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-02-11T18:28:51.130683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterux.com request_id=480a4181-0882-4ad5-a012-27bbeed255dc fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-11T18:28:21.185094+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=hipsterux.com request_id=e10b9259-fbac-428e-9e7c-1f2e6734b189 fwd="98.173.1.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Perhaps I there is an error with the config? I ask because the server seems to be trying to start up the development. But is that not why the Procfile specifies what to do? what am I missing here?

---

**Side Note**

I actually managed to get a different blog running successfuly on Heroku, when following the same tutorial. I now think that the problem might be beause of left over files from DocPad or Rails that I might be causing conflicts, or the actual database connected to my app.

Comment: Hey, if you want, you can also open a support ticket with Heroku: https://help.heroku.com/

Comment: @friism Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up just switching to AWS though. Far better support for Ghost.

Comment: It might have something to do with the NPM cache: https://coderwall.com/p/jjcpra/clean-heroku-npm-cache I solved a similar issue.